# What is the best way to track click events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

It's possible to track click events through Google Tag Manager and also through custom Javascript.  It's not terribly difficult to do this either way, and so my preference is to simply configure Google Tag Manager to capture a few dozen selected Click events.  However, I'm not aware of any pros or cons for doing this one way or the other?

If Google Tag Manager is already installed and loaded on my website, is there any reason why I should NOT use it for capturing click events?  Are there any compelling performance reasons or arguments that can be made that capturing Custom Events using Google Tag Manager might "slow" down a webpage?

Comment: The question does not belong here as it is too general. 
However, GTM is asynchronous tag container and does not impact page load. In any case,  you mentioned it is already there so I suggest to make best use of it.

Answer (score 0):

- You are unlikely to come up with a more robust solution than one that has been tested by a battalion of Google engineers
- You load the GTM code in any case, so you might as well use it
- If you want to use the built-in click variables (click text, click classes etc.) then you'd have to use the built-in click events

It is possible to slow down a page via GTM by unwise use of custom HTML tags or by loading tags that in turn load scripts from third party sources, but I bet you a good lunch that you won't come up with a solution that is at the same time as performant and as broadly applicable as the solution built into GTM.